# How to use spritemap technique in Nuxt 3 application?

Tags: nuxt.js, vite

I have a Nuxt 3 application and I want to use svg spritemap.

That is, put .svg files in the `/assests/svg/<name>.svg` folder and use them in the application like this:

```html
<svg>
   <use xlink:href="spritemap.svg?#<name>"></use>
</svg>
```

I found the `@nuxtjs/svg` plugin but I can't get it to work.
Connecting it as in the documentation, I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/_nuxt/assets/svg/example.svg') is not a valid name.
```

How can I make a spritemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s hard to do in Nuxt. But it's possible.

I created MIT lib on `npm` (`nuxt-svg-spritemap`) for this. Read [README.md](https://github.com/Aleksandr-JS-Developer/nuxt-svg-spritemap#readme) for more details.